# Why is the $\vec k$ space in solid state physics discretized?

Tags: solid-state-physics, fourier-transform, crystals, discrete

I can't find a satsifying explanaition for the fact that the components of the $\vec k$ vector only take discretized values $$k_i = 2\pi n_i/L_i \qquad i\in {x,y,z}$$ with $L_i$ being the periodicity in the corresponding direction.
I know Bloch's theorem, i.e. $\Psi_{\vec k + \vec K}(\vec r) = \Psi_{\vec k}(\vec r) $ where $\vec K$ is  a vector of the reciprocal lattice and the wave functions being Bloch functions $$\Psi_{\vec k}(\vec r) = u_{\vec k}(\vec r) e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r}.$$

I believe I have the necessary "puzzle blocks" to solve the question, I just can't put them together properly.
Please give me other suggestions/ways to derive the discretized values of $k$ in momentum space.

Comment: Periodic boundary conditions

Comment: (enforced at the "edges" ($0$ and $L$) of the entire crystal. Your textbook should discuss this quite early on)

Comment: No I checked three textbooks and all of them just put the formua...

Comment: Which three textbooks did you check?

Comment: Recall that atom positions in a crystal lattice are discrete, so their Fourier transform needs to be as well.

Comment: See: F. Bloch, Z. Physick, 52, 555 (1928). See also: Floquet's Theorem

Comment: See also: Kittle "Elementary Solid State Physics" at pages 152-154 (the section titled "Wave Functions in a Periodic Lattice)

Comment: See also: Harrison "Electronic Structure and the Properties of Solids" (2nd Edition) at page 33.

Comment: Thanks, the textbooks are a lot better than their german counterparts. I swear, the three available in our library don't even mention it...

Answer (score 1):

I believe  I found the proper way to do it with Bloch's theorem and due to the other replies:

\begin{align*}
  \Psi_{\vec k}(\vec r+L_i \vec e_i) &=  \Psi_{\vec k}(\vec r)\qquad \forall i\in{x,y,z} \\
  e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r} &= e^{i\vec k \cdot \left(\vec r + L_i \vec e_i\right)} \\
   e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r} &=e^{i\vec k \cdot \vec r} e^{ik _iL_i} \\
   1 & = e^{ik _iL_i}  
\end{align*}
$    \Rightarrow k _iL_i = n_i2\pi \Leftrightarrow k_i = \frac{n_i 2\pi}{L_i} \qquad n_i \in \mathbb{Z} $